# Javax.sound direct control over audio line

Tags: java, audio

Is there any way how can i feed direct input of the audio Line in java so i can make a synthesizer?

I tried feeding binary data to audio input Stream. It did not work

When it didn't work i assume that i feeding wrong data so i got a wave file and after figuring out where audio data was located and fed it in.

But it still didn't work

here is the source code:

```
//audio.bin is just a .wav file
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class main{
    public static Mixer mixer;
    public static Clip clip;
    public static AudioInputStream audioStream;
    public static InputStream inputStream;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File file = new File("audio.bin");
        
        byte[] files = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        
        Mixer.Info[] mx = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        //for(int i=0;i<mx.length;i++){
        //  System.out.println(i+"="+mx[i]);
        //}
        mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mx[0]);
        
        //Port.Info.SPEAKER;
        byte[] seq = new byte[files.length-0x56];
        int j=0x56;
        for(int i=0;i<seq.length;i++){
            seq[i]=files[j];
            j++;
            //System.out.println(seq[i]);
        }
        
        inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(files);
        
        AudioFormat format;
        DataLine.Info dataInfo = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, null);
        try{
            clip = (Clip)mixer.getLine(dataInfo);
            format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,44100,16,2,4,44100,false);
            audioStream = new AudioInputStream(inputStream,format,files.length);
            clip.open(audioStream);
            clip.start();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
        
    }
}


/*
        
        
        
        
        
        try{
            clip = (Clip)mixer.getLine(dataInfo);
            //AudioInputStream audioStream=;
            //clip.Open();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
*/
```

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? I got a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line unsupported: interface Clip` at `clip = (Clip)mixer.getLine(dataInfo);`, but can't tell if this is the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to directly play back audio data that you have synthesized, you should use the class `SourceDataLine` for output, not `Clip`.

For example, for a predefined `SourceDataLine` named *sdl* and a Byte[] named *buffer* of size 1024 (arbitrary size chosen):

```
while(isPlaying)
{
    buffer = getSomeAudioData();
    sdl.write(buffer, 0, 1024);
}
```

The audio data presented to the `SourceDataLine` will have to conform to the `AudioFormat` used when opening the `SourceDataLine`.